# Как в angular сделать валидацию одновременно на email и телефон, начинающийся с +38......?

Tags: angular, валидация

Я написал FormGroup и мне нужно сделать валидацию, что б проходил email либо телефон с началом `+38`. Как мне сделать одновременно проверку либо на email либо на телефон?

```
passwordRecovery_FG = new FormGroup({
    email_or_phone: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email
    ])
});
```

Validator 1: `/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/`
Validator 2: `/^\+38?\d{10}$/`

Comment: Создайте свой валидатор, с логикой которая вам нужна https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете вместо `Validators.email` использовать `Validators.pattern(регулярное выражение)`.
И написать регулярное выражение для валидации email или телефона.

Либо создать свой `Validator` и описать необходимую логику там.

Comment: @"Nikolya Shirshov" а как тогда мне сложить валидатор /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/     и   /^\+38?\d{10}$/     ?

Comment: Объеденить ваши регулярные выражения с помощью оператора ИЛИ ```|```.
Пример из регулярок выше:
```^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+)|(\+38?\d{10})$```

Comment: "@Nikolya Shirshov" спасибо, я это прописал в разметке pattern= , так как почему-то, если в валидаторе писал, то ошибка была. Но главное, что работает. Спасибо

Comment: @RakzinRoman предполагаю ошибка в том, что я забыл обернуть регулярку в ```/.../```.
Итог:
```/^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+)|(\+38?\d{10})$/```